# subset font without cmap how to build pdf ToUnicode section

Tags: pdf, mupdf, pdfium

I have a subset font(it is a CJK font), it doesn't have any cmap table. I want to use this font to build a pdf file.
my problem is  i don't know how to build the ToUnicode dictionary, is there any people can give me some suggestion? Thanks

i tried to iterate this font's glyph,failed to construct glyph index to unicode map

Comment: ToUnicode CMaps are optional, you don't need one.